# I can't double characters inside string with function

Tags: c++, string, function

I am trying to create a simple function that double the characters inside of a string and outputs the new string. Ex. "hello world" would become "hheelloo wwoorrlldd" However, with the function I wrote, the output is empty. If anyone can tell me why this is, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

```
using namespace std;
string doubleChar(string str) {
    string newString;
    for(int i =0;i<str.size();++i){
        newString[i] = str[i];
        newString[i+1] = str[i];
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: `newString[i+1] = str[i];` write past the bounds of the string and invokes *undefined behavior*.  Generally `operator[]` does not add new characters into a string, it only replaces existing ones, so your logic cannot work

Comment: You have to ensure that the storage for the new characters is allocated. `newString[i] = str[i]; newString[i+1] = str[i];` does access beyond storage. Try instead `newString += str[i]; newString += str[i];` (or ensure proper size of `newString` beforehand).

Comment: `newString.append(1, str[i]).append(1, str[i])` can replace the guts of your for-loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig As you mentioned `std::string::append()`: Why not `newString.append(2, str[i]);`? ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Derp. That'd be the whole forest-for-the-trees thing. that'll teach me to comment on SO in the wee hours of the morning. Of course you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altough the solution by songyuanyao is nice, I think more C++ functions can be used...

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// use string view, so a character array is also accepted
std::string DoubleChar(std::string_view const &str) noexcept {
    std::string newString;
    newString.reserve(str.size() * 2);
    for (auto character : str) { // use range based loop
        newString.append(2, character); // append the character twice
    }
    return newString;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string const str = "Hello world";

    std::cout << DoubleChar(str) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, `newString` is always empty, it doesn't contain any elements. Access on it like `newString[i]` and `newString[i+1]` leads to UB.

You need to add elements to it, e.g.

```
string doubleChar(const string& str) { // apply pass-by-reference to avoid copy
    string newString;
    newString.reserve(str.size() * 2); // reserve the capacity to avoid reallocation
    for(int i =0;i<str.size();++i){
        newString += str[i];
        newString += str[i];
        // or use push_back or append
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace std;
string doubleChar(string str) {
    string newString(str.size() * 2, '\0');
    for(int i =0;i<str.size();++i){
        newString[2*i] = str[i];
        newString[2*i+1] = str[i];
    }
    return newString;
}
```

The length of result should be set twice of the input. And index should be multiplied by 2.

Comment: Allocation beforehand should prevent re-allocations while adding the characters (what is not the worst thing). Aside of this I even didn't recognize the issue with the index for writing... ;-)