# c++ string constructed as char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

currently learning strings, i have the following:

```
string s;
s[0]='a'; s[1]='b';
cout<<s;

string s; s.clear();
s+='a'; s+='b';
cout<<s;
```

I get empty string as output from 1st example, and the 2nd works fine. I get that the 1st is undef behavior and that we 'push' an element the second time instead of assigning a value.
Any more clarification will be appreciated

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: @UnholySheep probably a bit intimidating for a someone new to cpp. What you want is to construct a string, follow the link to the `method functions: (constructor)` section, and check the examples.

Comment: @M.A they asked for documentation and cppreference is the most reliable website that provides said documentation. Obviously a good book would be the right choice for a beginner

Comment: A near duplicate just from this morning: [SO: I can't double characters inside string with function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63951606/7478597)

Comment: The `string s;` declaration does not reserve space for any characters, accessing this empty string through `operator[]` is undefined behavior, you need to first create space for the characters with something like `s.resize(3);`. Here is some less intimidating documentation http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: Note that using member `at` i.e. `s.at(0)` instead of `s[0]` will throw an exception wich is nicer than plain undefined behavior.

Comment: @anastaciu I can't say that cplusplus is less intimidating.. its 90-ness of web design gives me creeps c_c

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, you kind of grow fond of it after some time. Give it a chance :)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
string s;
```

creates empty string

```cpp
s[0]='a'; s[1]='b';
```

this is undefined behavior, since empty string have size zero, so required buffer may not exists.
It "works" since all major compilers are using Small String Optimization (SSO). In this optimization size of string object, allows to keep small string inside that object not on a heap. As a result minimum [capacity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/capacity) of `std::string` is none zero (15 in gcc if I remember correctly).

```cpp
cout<<s;
```

Now deeding on how this stream operator is implemented it can print empty string (size size of string is zero) or "ab" or "ab<some thrash>".

On [gcc it prints nothing](https://godbolt.org/z/8vEcW7).

To fix it you can:

- resize string first `s.resize(2)`
- use [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back) API

Comment: Thank you, I thought that might be the case, yes i get empty string back as result.
Now:
       string s; s.clear();
 s+='a'; s+='b';
 cout<<s;
Works fine with proper output, I get that now we "push" the char instead of assigning it to a specific element. Any more clarification on the difference between the 2 will be appreciated.